# Amazon SES with Godaddy Domain - Fine with sending but not receiving

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a domain registered with GoDaddy. I am hosting it with Amazon EC2 so changed name servers that I got with EC2 after adding a route 53 zone. Also have elastic IP attached to the EC2 and hosting works fine.

The problem is with e-mail. I want to use the domain's email id (contact@domain.com) to send e-mails and receive emails in Godaddy. Amazon SES is configured to send the e-mails. The domain is verified but I cannot verify the e-mail id as no e-mails are being received to the ID. When I send any e-mail to the email id contact@domain.com i receive error as below.

The error that the other server returned was:
550 5.1.1  Recipient not found.  http://x.co/irbounce

I want to send e-mail using Amazon SES and receive with Godaddy. Email sending is working fine but receiving fails.

Can you please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before I was having the same issue. I contacted Godaddy Support Team and they provided CNAME,TXT, SRV and MX type data.
For each I created RecordSet into my aws and my issue got resolved.You can create RecordSet as per your requirement.I hope this will help.